How do I change the size of a custom button
I am trying to change the size of a custom Button in my app but the size (width) stays the same no matter what I do

My code can be found here:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomAppButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final String title;
  final double? height;
  final double? width;

  const CustomAppButton({
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.title,
    this.height = 64, 
    this.width = 284, 
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: width, // Force button to have this width
      height: height, // Force button to have height
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

How do I fix this and get the button to be that size?

put sizedBox as child of ElevatedButton. Also set padding of button as 0 as they will take some space from height/width

you just need to make sure that the button respects the width and height you’re passing. You can do that by adding the minimumSize in the button’s style.
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: onPressed,
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      minimumSize: Size(width ?? 284, height ?? 64), // This line ensures the size
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
    ),
    child: Text(
      title,
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  )

Basically, the minimumSize inside ElevatedButton.styleFrom() makes sure the button will have the width and height you want. This should fix your problem!

Thanks guys. @sinnoor c & rahul
I tried, but it still doesn't change the width. it just stays the same

could it be as a result of my theme file?
class AppTheme {
  static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
   .....
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: AppColors.white,
          textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
      ));
}


can you show me where you are using the custom button?

CustomAppButton(                   onPressed: () {                     Navigator.push(                       context,                       MaterialPageRoute(                         builder: (BuildContext context) => const SupportPage(),                       ),                     );                   },                   title: 'Back to support page',                 ),

Wrap Elevated button with FractionallySizedBox Widget..

To use fixedSize property you can change height and width.
ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      fixedSize: Size(width, height)
                    ),
                    onPressed: (){}, child: SizedBox()),

You can adjust this in you code.
